# Passing parameters into Javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html template that I am using in my Django project.  I have a string that is defined in my Django view that I want to pass to javascript in my html template, but I am having trouble getting it to work.  There are two different strings, and the one displayed depends on the state of the toggle.

**The strings created in my view (and when properly displayed) look like this**:

`ATS_string_true`:

```
2015-123-01:34:39 CDS_FSW_FLASH_PLAYBK_STOP 
2015-123-01:34:41 CDS_FSW_FLASH_REPLAY_REQ TLM_DATA_TYPE=0 START_BLOCK=7 NUM_BLOCKS=3
2015-123-01:34:43 CDS_FSW_FLASH_REPLAY_REQ TLM_DATA_TYPE=1 START_BLOCK=300 NUM_BLOCKS=12
2015-123-01:34:51 CDS_FSW_FLASH_PLAYBK_STOP
```

and `ATS_string_false`:

```
[Ref task: SAT_F7_COMM_NOMINAL_31_op ] 2015-123-01:34:39 CDS_FSW_FLASH_PLAYBK_STOP
```

However, the string in the error message looks like this:

```
[Ref task: &lt;SAT_F7_COMM_NOMINAL_31_op&gt; ] &gt;&gt; 2015-123-01:34:39 CDS_FSW_FLASH_PLAYBK_STOP  
[Ref task: &lt;SAT_F7_COMM_NOMINAL_31_op&gt; ] &gt;&gt; 2015-123-01:34:41 CDS_FSW_FLASH_REPLAY_REQ TLM_DATA_TYPE=0 START_BLOCK=7 NUM_BLOCKS=3 
[Ref task: &lt;SAT_F7_COMM_NOMINAL_31_op&gt; ] &gt;&gt; 2015-123-01:34:43 CDS_FSW_FLASH_REPLAY_REQ TLM_DATA_TYPE=1 START_BLOCK=300 NUM_BLOCKS=12
```

**My html/js looks like this**:

```
{% if ATS %}
  <div class="panel panel-heading">
    <h3 class="text-center">ATS</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="checkbox disabled">
      <label>
        <input id="ATS_debug" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle">
        ATS Debug
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="ATS" style="background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px;">
      <p>{{ ATS_string_false | linebreaks }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#ATS_debug').change(function() {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $('#ATS').html({{ATS_string_true}});
        } else {
          $('#ATS').html({{ATS_string_false}});
        }
      })
    })
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

I'm getting an *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier* error at `$('#ATS').html({{ATS_string_true}});`.  Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Going from what I know about server pages and server templates, @RexOverflow is correct. You need to put those values into quotes so the result is proper js/html.

Comment: @Sinistralis I just deleted my comment. So, don't refer it now. @ Nursultan has answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap a variable {{ATS_string_true}} into "" like this:

`$('#ATS').html("{{ATS_string_true}}");`

Because Django doesn't do it for you).

Comment: The same goes for any server page/template language.

Comment: Ahh.  It's always the simple things that get me.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in quotes as @Nursultan just answered. The templating engines only concern about **what to replace** with **what**. The `{{ATS_string_true}}` part will be *exactly* replaced by the value of the variable `ATS_string_true`. Now, have a look at what your code which throws error:

```
$("#ATS").html({{ATS_string_true}});
```

Also,

```
$("#ATS").html({{ATS_string_false}});
```

Here consider: `var ATS_string_true = "I am the true value";`

The `.html()` method of jQuery expects the first parameter to be a string. If you do not wrap it in quotes, it will look as:

```
$("#ATS").html(I am the true value); // Invalid JS
```

But if you will add quotes like as suggested; the final processed template will look like:

```
$("#ATS").html("I am the true value"); // Valid JS
```